# Error Message: Control reached end of procedure without RETURN

Tags: postgresql, triggers

I have a nice table in POSTGRES:

```
CREATE TABLE public.pasajeros
(
    direccion_residencia character varying COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
    nombre character varying COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
    pasajero_id integer NOT NULL DEFAULT nextval('pasajeros_pasajero_id_seq'::regclass),
    fecha_nacimiento date,
    CONSTRAINT pasajeros_pkey PRIMARY KEY (pasajero_id)
)
```

I tried to add a trigger every time a new pasajero is inserted, a table stores the new value of total registers, so I created a new table:

```
CREATE TABLE public.cont_pasajeros
(
    total integer,
    tiempo time with time zone,
    id_t integer NOT NULL DEFAULT nextval('cont_pasajeros_id_t_seq'::regclass),
    CONSTRAINT cont_pasajeros_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id_t)
)
```

Then I created a new function to be includen in the trigger:

```
DECLARE
    count_ integer :=0;
BEGIN
    count_ := (SELECT count (*) FROM pasajeros);
    RAISE NOTICE 'number of registers %', count_;
    INSERT INTO cont_pasajeros (total,tiempo) VALUES (count_, now()); 
END
```

Then I created the trigger 'in perse':

```
CREATE TRIGGER trigger_ 
AFTER INSERT ON pasajeros
FOR EACH ROW 
EXECUTE PROCEDURE my_func();
```

The problem occured when I tried to add a new tuple into the table 'pasajeros':

```
INSERT INTO public.pasajeros(
    direccion_residencia, nombre, fecha_nacimiento)
    VALUES ('calle 1 a', 'benito', '2000-05-01');
```

a error occurred:

**Error Message: Control reached end of procedure without RETURN**

What I did wrong? apparently everything is normal. I am using pgAdmin4

Answer (score 1):

This is the solution I found: I modified the code of the function to include the sstatement `RETURN NULL`.

1. I drop the function:

   ```
   DROP FUNCTION public.my_func();
   ```
2. execute the new code, to include the sentence RETURN NULL

   ```
   CREATE FUNCTION public.my_func()
       RETURNS trigger
       LANGUAGE 'plpgsql'
       COST 100
       VOLATILE NOT LEAKPROOF
   AS $BODY$
   DECLARE
       count_ integer :=0;
   BEGIN
       count_ := (SELECT count (*) FROM pasajeros);
       RAISE NOTICE 'number of registers %', count_;
       INSERT INTO cont_pasajeros (total,tiempo) VALUES (count_, now());
       RETURN NULL;  -- added to fix the error
   END
   $BODY$;

   ALTER FUNCTION public.my_func()
       OWNER TO postgres;
   ```